# KeyError = 'cover' Issues accesing values with igdb-api-v4

Tags: python, api, keyerror

I am working with the IGDB database using a python wrapper called igdb-api-v4 and I am having some trouble isolating the values from the dictionary generated within. Below is the code that I am running. (client_id and token are placeholders for this conversation)

```
from igdb.wrapper import IGDBWrapper
import json

wrapper = IGDBWrapper("client_id", "token")

'''With a wrapper instance already created'''
# JSON API request
byte_array = wrapper.api_request(
            'games',
            'fields name, summary, cover; offset 0; where name="Halo"*;',
            
          )
# parse into JSON however you like...
message = json.loads(byte_array)

def reader(message):
  
  for game in message:
    result = []

    # print(game)
    # print("")
    cover = game['cover'] 
    result.append(cover)
    name = game['name']
    result.append(name)
    for i in game:
      if game['summary'] == True:
        summary = game['summary']
        result.append(game['summary'])
    print('')
    print(result)


reader(message)
```

After running I receive this error message:
I also receive it when trying to isolate the value in other ways. Is there a special way I am supposed to be accessing these cover art values? My plan is to incorporate this into a Django project if that helps.

> KeyError: 'cover'

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own. The way to access the url value is to request the cover like so.

```
byte_array = wrapper.api_request(
            'games',
            'fields name,summary,cover.url; offset 0; where name="Halo"*; sort first_release_date;',
          )
```